# PHPExcel - Get date with forced format

Tags: php, excel, date, phpexcel

I use PHPexcel in a php application.
I used `->getFormattedValue()` to get date from excel worksheet.

When I use excel file A it gives me the following date format: `05/11/2016`
But with the file B it gives following format :  `05-Nov-17`

How to force a date format in order to get a format like this  `05-Nov-17` all the time? How to convert it directly from `PHPExcel` to `PHP` date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can return the raw value from the cell using the `getValue()` method,

```
$excelTimestampValue = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getCell('A12')
    ->getValue();
```

which will return an MS Excel serialized timestamp value; that is, a floating point number representing the number of days since 1st January 1900 (or 1st January 1904, depending on which calendar the spreadsheet file is using). From that timestamp value, you have a number of options:

Convert that timestamp to a unix timestamp, which you can then format however you wish using PHP's `date()` function.

```
$unixTimestamp = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($excelTimestampValue);
echo date('d-M-Y', $unixTimestamp);
```

Convert that timestamp to a PHP DateTime object, which you can then format however you wish using the `format()` method.

```
$dto = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject($excelTimestampValue);
echo $dto->format('d-M-Y');
```

Format it directly to a string, using an MS Excel date format mask.

```
echo PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::toFormattedString($excelTimestampValue, 'dd-mmm-yyyy');
```

Comment: Is there any probability that the date will be lost if the program uses 1900 calendar instead of 1904  by mistake?

Comment: Why would the date be lost? Whether the Excel file uses the 1900 or 1904 calendar is identified when the file is loaded, and stored in PHPExcel, so when you convert to a unix timestamp or a DateTime object using `ExcelToPHP()` or `ExcelToPHPObject()`, it knows which calendar was used and adjusts accordingly

Comment: PHPExcel knows well witch calendar to use? So, no fear. thanks